# errors in android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS

Tags: android

I have designed 2 applications,

1) Which is a `service` and is running in the `background`.

2) Which runs in the foreground, which just has an `EditText`. now, i want to insert some values into EditText using the service. In logs i found, the error `not allowed to start intent without permissions  .INJECT_EVENTS`

I have put the permissions in the manifest file of both the apps, it's still giving me a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because ordinary Android SDK applications cannot hold the `INJECT_EVENTS` permission. That can only be held by applications signed by the same signing key as was used to sign the firmware.

Moreover, this is a really strange way to have two applications communicate. Android has a wide range of IPC options -- please use one. Or, do not make them be two separate applications.

Comment: can't i just run them on the emulator and check?

Comment: About method of communication, in real application I have to implement the key press event in a 3rd party application. If I can do it in my application, there might be some way to do that in the 3rd party app too.

Comment: @Pallavi: "I have to implement the key press event in a 3rd party application" -- fortunately, that is impossible, except for custom firmware, for obvious security reasons.

Comment: k... Thanks a lot. you saved a lot of re-search work for me ;) :D